# SharePoint 2013: New Item Link

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, newform, new-item

I am trying to change the default url of the "new item" link in SharePoint 2013 list.

Is it possible to change it OOTB? Or any other possible way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please add more details around your requirement.

Comment: I agree with sssreddy. I think I know what you are asking but would like to be sure. Can you please provide more details as to what you are specifically looking to do?

Comment: SharePoint List "new item" link opens up the newform.asp per default. I am asking how to make it so that it opens up a different form.